# What would be the practical consequences of ZPP=exptime

Tags: complexity-theory, time-complexity

What would be the practical consequences of ZPP=exptime.
It would be pretty ridiculous if the was true but what if it was?

Answer (score 1):

If **ZPP** = **EXPTIME** then **NP** $\subseteq$ **ZPP**, which implies **NP** $\subseteq$ **BPP**.  As described in Russell Impagliazzo's informal paper ["A personal view of average-case complexity"](https://stuff.mit.edu/afs/sipb/project/reading-group/past-readings/2009-06-08-five-worlds.pdf), we would be living in a world he calls *Algorithmica*.

> Algorithmica is the world in which $P = NP$ or some moral equivalent, e.g. $NP \subseteq BPP$. [...]
>
> Such a method of automatically producing a solution for a problem from the method of recognizing a valid solution would revolutionize computer science. Seemingly intractable algorithmic problems would become trivial. Almost any type of optimization problem would be easy and automatic; for example, VLSI design would no longer use heuristics, but could instead produce exactly optimal layouts for problems once a criterion for optimality was given. Programming languages would not need to involve instructions on how the computation should be performed. Instead, one would just specify the properties that a desired output should have in relation to the input.

And so on.  Read the paper for more extrapolation on this topic, along with the consequences of less fantastic algorithmic complexity conjectures being true.  And observe @Dmitry's caveat: Knowing a problem is in a tractable complexity class isn't the same as having an efficient algorithm for the problem that takes advantage of that fact.

Theoretically, **ZPP = EXPTIME** implies **EXPTIME** $\subseteq$ **BPP**.  Since we already know **P** $\subset$ **EXPTIME** we have **P** $\subset$ **BPP** as well, which means there are some polynomial-time randomized algorithms that cannot be derandomized.  This is another way of saying that pseudo-random number generators will never be as effective as true randomness, algorithmically, which would be a very interesting result.

We know that **BPP** is low for itself, i.e. **BPP$^{BPP}$ = BPP**.  Therefore an **EXPTIME** no more powerful than **BPP** must be low for itself as well, which removes the separation between some exponential classes, e.g. **EXPTIME = EEXP = EE = EEE**.  This in turn makes some decidable but intractable problems simply decidable. For example, deciding the truth of first-order mathematical statements expressed in Presburger arithmetic would now be in **BPP**.

We also know that **BPP** $\subseteq \Sigma^P_2 \cap \Pi^P_2$.  Together with **EXPTIME** $\subseteq$ **BPP** this means that the polynomial hierarchy collapses to the second level; the oracle calls above that level do not offer any more computational power, as **EXPTIME** is powerful enough to capture all the rest of **PH**.  Since **P** is strictly a subset of **BPP** and **P** = **NP** would collapse **PH** completely, bringing **P** and **BPP** together, **ZPP** = **EXPTIME** would imply **P** $\neq$ **NP**.

[Edit] **NP** = **co-NP** would also be settled in the affirmative.

Comment: I think they are still talking about theoretical consequences, not practical ones. Practical consequences, similarly to "what happens if $P=NP$", will be along the lines "in all likelihood, nothing will change (unless we also design *practically efficient* algorithms)". So it'll revolutionize computer science, but won't change the world we live in.

Comment: NP=coNP would be settled in the affirmative. Since $ZPP\subseteq NP \subseteq EXPTIME$, we have $ZPP=NP$; and since $ZPP$ is closed under complement, $NP=ZPP=coZPP=coNP$. I suggested an edit to the post, I hope you don't mind.

Comment: "We know that BPP is low for itself, i.e. BPP$^{BPP}$ = BPP. Therefore an EXPTIME no more powerful than BPP must be low for itself as well" I actually am not sure it works like this for oracles. EXP still could invoke EXP oracle exponentially many times, whereas BPP could invoke EXP oracle only polynomially many times.